# execute lua string as lua code

Tags: lua, require

I want to share lua modules with coworkers. In order to get the latest version of shared modules I want to store and fetch them with a web server.

My questions is:

Is it possible to load lua code directly from http request or string?

I want to achieve something like that :

```
module = [[
    local sharedModule = {}
    function sharedModule.greet(name) print("hello " .. name) end  
    return sharedModule
]]
greeter = require (module)
greeter.greet("john")
```

Maybe this is not the right thing to do. Is there a better approach than this one?

Comment: You're looking for [`load`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-load). However, I'd advise hosting the module internally, and have the users download/install it acccordingly.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thank you for the quick response. And thanks for the advise. I will set up security check before accessing lua modules

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's [a whole section](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.html) in *Programming in Lua* devoted to that. Your needs will be directly fulfilled with `loadstring` in Lua 5.1 and older, or `load` in Lua 5.2 and newer.

I would carefully verify the code you're actually executing, though. At the very least, version it (running a wrong version would most probably end up in all sorts of problems, if the code being run depends on the environment being in a certain state). Optimally checksum and sign the code, and verify the signature before doing anything. If your environment isn't protected, this is essentially a huge backdoor opening.

You could also use `rings` library to isolate the code you're running *within* the Lua environment itself. It might not be airtight security-wise, but should at least prevent the received code from crashing your application if/when it goes awry.