# Is it possible to make it impossible for loadstring to be equal to print? lua

Tags: lua, obfuscation

Is this possible? So lets say that we have this script: loadstring("print('Hello')")() this script is really easy to get the source from by just doing:

```
loadstring = print
loadstring("print('Hello')")()
```

Is it possible to disable this? Btw this is for my obfuscator

I am really sorry if this thread was confusing, Thanks

Comment: Your code does print `print('Hello')` before raising an error `attempt to call a nil value` because `print` returns nothing.

Comment: no? That code will legit print out: "print('Hello')"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe helpful: [execute lua string as lua code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386060/execute-lua-string-as-lua-code).
So, the code must be:

```
trueloadstring = loadstring
loadstring = print
loadstring ("print('Hello')") -- prints "print('Hello')"
trueloadstring ("print('Hello')")() -- prints "Hello"
```