# Button that executes textbox contents roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a gui with a textbox where you type in for example print("Hello world!") you click a button and it executes it but I can't figure out the execute part I've tried this so far:

```
local ScrTxt = script.Parent.Parent.TextBox
local Button = script.Parent

Button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    print(ScrTxt.Text)
end)
```

Comment: When you ask a question, you should include what isn't working and the error message you're getting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [execute lua string as lua code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386060/execute-lua-string-as-lua-code)

Answer (score 0):

To execute a string as code, LoadStringEnabled must be enabled
[image: loadstringenabled]

Then, you can do this:

```lua
local ScrTxt = script.Parent.Parent.TextBox
local Button = script.Parent

Button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    loadstring(ScrTxt.Text)()
end)
```

Comment: It gives me an error saying "loadstring() is not available"

Comment: You need to enable loadstringenabled, like I said. Click "ServerScriptService" with properties open and click "LoadStringEnabled"

Comment: But I did is the gui supposed to be in ServerScriptService?

Comment: No. I think you would need to connect your ui with remote events. But I'm not 100% sure